# How to paste from iBooks without quotes and citation?

Tags: macos

Copy and pasting code snippets from iBooks sucks. It always puts quotes and a citation with the code snippet. Does anyone know how to paste without the quotes and citation?

```
“g++ --std=c++11 hello_client.cpp gen-cpp/HelloSvc.cpp -lthrift”

Excerpt From: Randy Abernethy. “The Programmer’s Guide to Apache Thrift MEAP v15.” iBooks.
```

Comment: Strangely, I don't have this problem with iBooks.

Answer (score -1):

That is a built-in feature of iBooks. You can use scripts to remove the citation.

https://gist.github.com/iandundas/7863c6c248f76e14a3a8

Comment: Could you "please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: The case described by @jhaagsma came true. The link is down, so this answer in now unhelpful.

Comment: Link works again, or so it seems. The code is explained on his blog, by the way: http://iandundas.com/blog/2015/9/9/remove-ibook-citations-with-a-keyboard-shortcut